# BSOD from Switching to Fullscreen Games

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I keep getting the Blue Screen of Death when a game opens in fullscreen. Let me describe what happens: I will log on to the computer, open Chrome and Minecraft, and click "Play" on the Minecraft launcher. I will start doing something in Chrome, but then Minecraft will open in full screen, and the computer will get the Blue Screen of Death. If, however, I am careful, and I make sure that I am on the desktop when Minecraft opens, it works fine.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible graphics driver issue? Check event viewer logs Application and System for errors related to the crash. If you post the exact error here, I can try to give you a more exact answer,

Comment: Where should I look?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most common error associated with fullscreen game errors is an outdated display driver or software.

The first and probably most simple fix is to make sure you have the latest version of Google Chrome. While Chrome may auto-update it is still possible for you to not have the latest version. Do not worry about the Minecraft launcher, as it self-updates after every launch.

After updating Chrome, restart your computer after saving and closing any open programs. After the restart, recreate the scenario and see if the error is fixed. If not, continue reading.

If you have been having this problem since you have started playing Minecraft it may be an outdated game driver, knowing that Minecraft relies on Java to run, and can cause issues with other programs if you have an outdated version of Java.

Make sure you have the latest version of Java as well as the right version for your computer, such as Java x64 for 64 bit systems, and Java x86 for 32 bit systems.

The Minecraft launcher will notify you of a mismatched OS and Java version in the launcher log tab, or when you launch Minecraft and try to load a world.

In your start menu you should have a folder named 'Java' with a program titled 'check for updates' inside the folder, run this program and click 'Update Now' on the bottom right of the resulting window. Java updater will open and say you have the latest version of Java or will guide you through the update process if there is one available. After the install, save and close any open windows and restart your computer. Once you have restarted, you may try to launch Minecraft again with Google Chrome open. If the problem persists, try the below:

If you are sure you have the latest Java version, or you have only been having this problem recently and was able to launch without error a few weeks or months ago, it may be a recent Minecraft Launcher or Google Chrome update causing incompatibilities with your video drivers. Once again, make sure your video drivers are up to date. Some stock PCs come with their own video driver update software, such as most PCs with Nvidia graphics cards. If you have a custom built PC or your PC did not come with it's own software, there is some freeware available online for driver updates. Be careful with where you download some from as it may contain malware. I recommend IOBit's Driver Booster. If this is not an option and you know the graphics processor in your computer, try the graphics manufacturer's website for the latest drivers.

However, if you are sure you have the latest Java and video driver versions, or after following the above you still have difficulties, carefully recreate the crash situation (make sure you save everything you have open) and take a picture of the BSOD with an external camera or phone, and post it this page to give people a better view of your problem.

Sorry for the long answer, just wanted to provide a detailed fix to your situation.

Comment: Apparently Chrome was not auto updating, it needed an admin password, but once I updated, it doesn't happen anymore, thanks.